# Implementation of "Add to existing contact"as in native dialer

Tags: iphone, addition, contacts, addressbook

I am looking for ways to implement something that is exactly similar to the "Add to existing contact" option in the native dialer application on the iPhone. 
That is, as soon as this option is selected, the PeoplePickerNavigationController is displayed, and once a contact is selected the number is added as a new phone number with an option to "Save" or "Cancel". 
   Any idea how to implement this?
I am not looking for methods with ABUnknownPersonViewController, because it gives the option to create a new contact and add to an existing one. What I am looking for is the direct jump to the behaviour of "Add to existing contact".

Comment: How will this be implemented? Will the user press a button that triggers this behavior?

Comment: Yes, that is the idea. User clicks a button, the entire address book is shown, then on selecting a person the number is added as a new number (with some label) for the chosen contact.